# Не выдержав своей вины / Не выдержав чувства вины

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

Как правильно сказать?
*Не выдержав **своей вины*** или *не выдержав **чувства вины***.

Answer (score 3):

**Газетная публицистика ― источник ненадежный;** некогда журналистам соблюдать правильную сочетаемость слов: более или менее приемлемо для слуха, и ладно.

Обратимся в Нацкорпус и проверим сочетаемость для ***не выдержав***. Результат: из 1000 примеров ни одного выражения ***не выдержав вины*** и только один пример ***не выдержав чувства (ненависти).***

Какой вывод? **Оба сочетания нехороши**, а ***не выдержав вины***, вероятно, и вовсе **неприемлемо.** Надо использовать другие, например: *Чувство вины было нестерпимо, он не мог больше выдержать этой муки.*  Что-то вроде этого.

**Это статистика, но как ее объяснить?**

Из словаря:

**ВЫДЕРЖАТЬ,**  1. что. Сохранить свои свойства, качества, подвергшись физическому воздействию (давлению, холоду и т.п.). В. напор воды. Мост не выдержит такой нагрузки. Сплав выдержит любой мороз. 2. что. **Стойко перенести; оказаться способным устоять, вытерпеть.** В. осаду. В. побои. Такой жизни не в.

Попробуем составить пару с НЕ и без НЕ: **не выдержать и  выдержать.** Если сочетаемость присутствует, **то возможны оба варианта.**

Итак, ***не выдержать вины ― выдержать вину.*** Сочетание проверки "не выдерживает", мы не говорим: Он выдержал свою вину. Выдержать свою вину было сложно.

**Примеры (что можно "не выдержать"):**

Я смешал крупу снова, **не выдержав этой новой муки**. [В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961)]

Однажды среди ночи она, **не выдержав пустоты бессонницы,** оделась и тихонько выскользнула на улицу. [Людмила Улицкая. 2000]

**Не выдержав этого испытания,** вырыл себе землянку и жил в ней всё лето, так он дождался построенного для него флигеля. [И. А. Забежинский. (2015.11.07)]

Может, конечно, нервы сдали, **не выдержав двухмесячного напряжения**. [Александр Щеголев. (2014)]

Часть флоры и фауны, **не выдержав изменений климата**, погибла. [коллективный. Снова о меченых нейтронах // «Знание-сила», 2013]

**Не выдержав одиночества и унижения**, Кирилл вскоре впал в чёрную меланхолию, порой ему, недавнему атеисту, даже мерещилось присутствие дьявола, вмешавшегося в его судьбу. [Ирина Грачёва. 2009]

Comment: Поддерживаю! Отвечая на вопрос, что верно, первое или второе,  нужно помнить, что можно ответить и так: ни то, ни другое.

Answer (score 2):

Выдержать - это устоять под тяжестью чего-то, в переносном значении под тяжестью вины. Вполне корректно: *человек не выдержал своей вины*, а вот чувство вины скорее не выдержит сердце человека, нервы и т.д.

Вот в Новостях: Не выдержав вины или испугавшись ответственности за свое преступление, он покончил с собой. И таких фраз много в газетной публицистике.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: **не выдержав чувства вины**.

Выражение ***чувство вины*** часто встречается в текстах, и речь в данном случае идет  об этом чувстве.

**Вина** ― это проступок, нельзя сказать ***не выдержать проступка***. **Чувство вины** ― это внутреннее ощущение, именно его не выдерживает человек.

Сравнить: Ей казалось иногда, что сердце у нее лопнет, **не выдержав чувства** ненависти, которое ей внушало каждое движение, каждый звук Драйера. [В. В. Набоков. Король, дама, валет (1927-1928)]

Из словаря: **ВИНА,**  1. **Проступок, провинность, преступление**. Доказать, признать вину. Загладить вину. Искупить свою вину. Не моя вина (не я виноват). // **Ответственность за такие действия.** **Не чувствовать за собой вины.** Возложить,  Поставить в вину кому-л. 2. Причина, источник (чего-л. нежелательного, неблагоприятного). Всему виной твоя оплошность.